# How can the jenkins build can be discarded if no download stream is triggered?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There are two jobs in my jenkins server

- job1 : build every 10 minutes to scan the events, if happens it triggers the downstream job2
- job2 : normal job mostly run once in the case.

**Problem:**
too many useless jenkins build for `job1` in the UI since it runs frequently.

It will be good if the build can be discarded if it doesn't trigger the downstream job.

**Solution so far:**, using [Discard Old build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) in post build action is one direction, but no clue how to get it works nicely.

Comment: There is a build aborter plugin, you could discard aborted jobs, just need to figure out how to abort the job if the build is not triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hints from @JamesD's comments, I can use several plugins to achieve this

[image]

1. Archive artifacts Plugin: to archive the `param.txt` files which is used to path to downstream jobs
2. Groovy Postbuild job Plugin: add the groovy script to check whether the `param.txt` exists or not. The build will be set to **Abort** if it doesn't exists
3. Discard Old Builds Plugin: will discard the **Abort** build